# What is happening under the hood that results in graphical artifacts? (not looking for a fix, just an explanation)

Tags: graphics, gpu, hardware, visual-glitch

Example of graphical artifiacts: [image]

I keep on seeing answers like "your GPU is overheating or damaged" and the like (my pic is actually of Play Station 2 emulation), but I wanna know what those problems are causing to happen that manifests itself this way on the screen.

Is it messing up draw instructions sent to the GPU?

Is the GPU fumbling some of the processing and the artifacts are it "smoothing" out the bad result?

In the case where its not a bad GPU, and the problem is unique to a single software, what kind of programming choices could cause this to happen? (i.e. things you could have done in the code to cause the problem on otherwise good hardware).

Comment: You might want to check out the blog of the Dolphin emulator's developers.  They frequently discuss graphical glitches and their causes.  I think your question cannot be answered as is as there are thousands of potential reasons for graphical glitches.  Lastly, why have you tagged this “assembly?”  I don't see any assembly code in your question.